# Some linux apps only work on certain desktop environments (DEs)?

Tags: gnome, kde, desktop-apps

On a recent DLN podcast episode one of them said 'such and such app doesn't run on KDE'. I was confused. I thought that, in general, any app written for linux can run on pretty much any DE. Is that true?

To be more precise, I thought that any linux app that can run on Ubuntu Gnome can run on KDE. Is that true?

I'm referring to apps that use a GUI interface.

Forgive my beginner question, I'm new to computer tech and linux. Thanks.

PS: None of the "Similar questions" offered answers my question.

Comment: AFAIK, after you install their dependencies, they should work on any DE.

Comment: Which exactly app do not work on which DE? Why should we consider to trust an opinion from random blogger?

Comment: I'm using Lubuntu currently (LXQt), but was once upon a time a very happy GNOME 2 user (ie. GTK2), and never stopped using apps from those days (ie. GNOME apps that are now GTK3).  After GNOME2 ended; I used KDE, then XFCE, and even briefly MATE and the same apps run in all. The use of GTK3 apps on my (LX)Qt5 desktop means I'm wasting RAM as my desktop needs Qt5 libs for the desktop, but GTK3 libs for the apps, but that is my decision; and something I wouldn't do if this box only had 2GB of RAM or less.